# list_object not working for cross-account with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm trying to download a file from S3 path in another account using AWS Lambda & python. I'm able to download the files if I provide full key to the copy_object. This will not work for me on a day-to-day scenario as there's no notification and my scheduled lambda code has to check for the presence of file using wildcards. But I'm getting Access denied(An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied) error while trying to list the contents of that bucket even though I have get & list permissions added.

I have the following policy added to my lambda role.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<src S3 bucket>/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<src S3 bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<src bucket account id>:key/<src bucket kms key>"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the source bucket, they have added the below permissions for my lambda role

```
 {
            "Sid": <>,
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<my account id>:role/LambdaRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<src S3 bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<src S3 bucket>/*"
            ]
        },
```

Python code to pull the file

```
def get_s3_file(event):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    file_name = file_key+'test.txt'
    logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
    objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=file_key)
    for object in objects:
        print(object.key)
        if object.key.endswith('.txt'):
            print(object.key)
    copy_source = {'Bucket': bucket_name,'Key': file_name} 
    s3_c.copy_object(Bucket='<my bucket>', Key='/data/', CopySource=copy_source, ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is due to KMS. If the lambda and bucket are in different accounts, lambda will not have automatically access to kms key in the second account. You have to modify **KMS key policy** to allow for that. So try adding lambda role arn to the KMS policy in the second account.